# Why does my Heroku app work only for me and no one else?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, git, heroku

A few days ago, I deployed a heroku app on a free account at the following url: 
http://www.thebusybee.io/api/v1/tasks

On the day of, I edited the DNS records to point to http://busybeeapp.herokuapp.com ([screenshot link](https://www.dropbox.com/s/vy7zwu0ldpar9fs/Screenshot%202014-04-29%2020.08.42.png)) -- and added the new domain to my heroku settings.

There are 4 total apps deployed on my heroku account but the busybee.io is the only one with a custom domain, and it's the first time I've ever done this.

Currently, the routes are only set up to accept GET and POST requests and it performs successful requests for me in the browser and in my terminal. But almost everyone else who tries to access the url says it doesn't work.

A successful response should return an array of JSON data that looks like this:

```
[
  {
    id: 1,
    description: "first task",
    created_at: "2014-04-25T02:27:11.005Z",
    updated_at: "2014-04-25T02:27:11.005Z"
  },
  {
    id: 2,
    description: "can you see me?",
    created_at: "2014-04-25T04:20:15.841Z",
    updated_at: "2014-04-25T04:20:15.841Z"
  }
]
```

Am I supposed to get more dynos? Does this have something to do with limited number of requests? I'm not 100% clear on how to resolve this issue.

For comparison, here's a link to the app at the herokuapp subdomain: http://busybeeapp.herokuapp.com/api/v1/tasks

Here's a link to the github repo: https://github.com/thisisbrianhan/busybee

And here's my terminal output:

```
$ curl -I http://www.thebusybee.io/api/v1/tasks

HTTP/1.1 200 OK
Cache-Control: max-age=0, private, must-revalidate
Content-length: 0
Content-Type: application/json; charset=utf-8
Date: Tue, 29 Apr 2014 23:43:09 GMT
Etag: "e11ceb6324cdea6fa03728839c7ceaa8"
Server: WEBrick/1.3.1 (Ruby/2.1.1/2014-02-24)
X-Content-Type-Options: nosniff
X-Frame-Options: SAMEORIGIN
X-Request-Id: d968dfad-a7c2-432d-b343-d1153bab17f4
X-Runtime: 0.008214
X-Xss-Protection: 1; mode=block
Connection: keep-alive


$ hosts www.thebusybee.io

www.thebusybee.io is an alias for busybeeapp.herokuapp.com.
busybeeapp.herokuapp.com is an alias for us-east-1-a.route.herokuapp.com.
us-east-1-a.route.herokuapp.com has address 23.21.41.227
```

Please let me know if I should provide you with more information to better resolve this issue.

Thanks for your time & help!

Comment: Define, "Doesn't work". I'm able to get to the page, though I get a JSON response. Is that not what it's supposed to do? Don't just add more dynos - if your app doesn't with with one why would adding more make it work? You gotta have a solid reason for adding stuff rather than just shooting in the dark. :)

Comment: it works for me. in my understanding of "works".

Comment: Thanks, @jefflunt -- yes, getting a JSON response is the expected successful response (I've updated the OP to make this clear now).

Comment: maybe when you enabled your domain, it has not been propagated yet to DNS servers.

Comment: Seems @akonsu's suggestion is a very likely one. DNS can take up to a couple of days to propagate globally. If your next question is, "How can it make the DNS propagation go faster," the answer to that question is, "You don't. You just wait. It's supposed to work that way." :)

Comment: Yeah, I deployed and set up my DNS records sometime before the weekend , but it's a good sign that the URL worked for both of you, @jefflunt and akonsu

Answer (score 1):

If you've waited and @akonsu's answer wasn't enough for you, keep in mind that heroku spins down their single dyno free apps pretty regularly. It takes several moments for it to spin back up and start your app when a page is requested.  You would need to pay for a second dyno for always on.  Perhaps your other users were just timing out waiting for the app to start.  Either way you'll have to better define "doesn't work."

Disclaimer: It's been a while since I've hosted on heroku.

Comment: Thanks for the answer -- "doesn't work" means that other users don't see the JSON data that should appear when hitting http://www.thebusybee.io/api/v1/tasks and I'm not sure if they're timing out or receiving another type of error. Users don't have a problem when visiting the heroku url, busybeeapp.herokuapp.com/api/v1/tasks and I understand performance on a single dyno should be slow, but my site should still support multiple users visiting it if the heroku subdomain address works for more than one user at a time.

Answer (score 0):

This is as close to an answer I can muster, but now http://www.busybee.io/api/v1/tasks seems to be successfully and consistently responding with JSON data as it should.

I fiddled around with my heroku domains and my DNS records where I registered my domain name. 
Before I had many possible domains setup to this app (wildcard domains, naked root domain, api subdomain) and I had many DNS records pointing to those domains.

With that configuration, it resulted in a lot inconsistent responses when users navigated to the url path I provided.

So now my DNS records are edited to look like [this](https://www.dropbox.com/s/vy7zwu0ldpar9fs/Screenshot%202014-04-29%2020.08.42.png) as the OP indicates. 
The heroku host and domain settings are now correctly configured as well.

It was a small issue but I'm really thankful for those people who took the time to look into this and help me better understand the Heroku deployment process a bit better.

Cheers